# executing a customizable function after an animation

Tags: swift

I'm trying to execute a function after an animation. This will need to be a different function each time so I introduced an argument as a CGFunction. What's weird though is that when I'm running this code I actually get "yes" printed to console which means that it's working fine. But the program crashes a few seconds later, and what's even weirder is that "view running" actually never gets printed to console. If anybody could take a look and let me know what's causing this problem I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addWelcomeLabel()
            print("view running")
        }

        func addWelcomeLabel() {
            let welcomeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 100))
            welcomeLabel.alpha = 0.0
            welcomeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
            welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome"
            welcomeLabel.textAlignment = .center
            welcomeLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
            welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 160/255)
            view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
            fadeViewInThenOut(view: welcomeLabel, delay: 5, afterCompletion: hello() as! CGFunction)
        }

        func fadeViewInThenOut(view: UILabel, delay: TimeInterval, afterCompletion: CGFunction) {
            let animationDuration = 1.00
            let action = afterCompletion
                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: animationDuration,
                    delay: 1,
                    animations: { () -> Void in view.alpha = 1}) { (Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: animationDuration,
                    delay: delay,
                    animations: { () -> Void in view.alpha = 0},
                    completion: { finished in action //insert here what i want it to do after
                    })
            }
        }
        func hello(){
            print("yes")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use a CGFunction? This is Swift; you can just use a function. Unlike CGFunctions, a Swift function is a first class citizen and can be passed around and retained in the way you're trying to do.

Comment: Also note that you don't want to say `in action`, you want to say `in action()` — you want to _call_ the function, not return it.

Comment: @matt when I replace CGFunction as with function it just says it's an undeclared type. I tried using the auto-fill/complete feature but it just suggests CGFunction.    ``func fadeViewInThenOut(view: UILabel, delay: TimeInterval, afterCompletion: function)``

Comment: Well the keyword `function` is not a type. You have to say the type of the function, using its signature. I suggest you learn some more Swift before proceeding. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID174

Comment: @MatthewKaplan just pass a function as closure  look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addWelcomeLabel()

}


        func addWelcomeLabel() {
            let welcomeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 100))
            welcomeLabel.alpha = 0.0
            welcomeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
            welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome"
            welcomeLabel.textAlignment = .center
            welcomeLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
            welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 160/255)
            view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
            fadeViewInThenOut(view: welcomeLabel, delay: 5, afterCompletion: hello())
        }

        func fadeViewInThenOut(view: UILabel, delay: TimeInterval, afterCompletion: (())) {
            let animationDuration = 1.00
            let action = afterCompletion
                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: animationDuration,
                    delay: 1,
                    animations: { () -> Void in view.alpha = 1}) { (Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: animationDuration,
                    delay: delay,
                    animations: { () -> Void in view.alpha = 0},
                    completion: { finished in action //insert here what i want it to do after
                        print("action")
                    })
            }
        }
        func hello(){
            print("yes")
        }
    }
```